# MySQL cluster unattended installation

Tags: mysql-cluster, debconf

I would like to install MySQL cluster without manual intervention. I tried following the steps on the official guide but couldn't quite get it to work.

What I have so far...

```
DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
sudo apt-get install -y debconf-utils

# set mysql configs
echo "mysql-apt-config mysql-apt-config/select-server select mysql-cluster-7.6" | sudo debconf-set-selections
echo "mysql-apt-config mysql-apt-config/select-tools select Disabled" | sudo debconf-set-selections
echo "mysql-apt-config mysql-apt-config/select-preview select Disabled" | sudo debconf-set-selections
echo "mysql-apt-config mysql-apt-config/select-product select Ok" | sudo debconf-set-selections
echo "mysql-community-server mysql-community-server/root-pass password $SQL_ROOT_PASS" | sudo debconf-set-selections
echo "mysql-community-server mysql-community-server/re-root-pass password $SQL_ROOT_PASS" | sudo debconf-set-selections

# Add apt repository
wget https://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql-apt-config_0.8.13-1_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i mysql-apt-config_0.8.13-1_all.deb
```

Using `debconf-set-selections` I'm able to correctly set the selections. However, upon executing `sudo dpkg -i mysql-apt-config_0.8.13-1_all.deb`, I still get the installation screen prompting to select the packages. Am I missing something?